# How to know how much data an app uses in one day?

Tags: 8.0, data-usage

I want to know (*for statistical purposes*) how many data a particular app is using in one day.

I want to know how much of that data was over `cellular data` and how much was over `Wifi`.

Is there any way to know this info in `Windows Phone` without carrier intervention, root or developer thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Monitor usage

[Data Sense](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/use-data-sense-to-track-data-usage), which was introduced with the GDR2 update (aka Update 2), allows you to track your data usage over time. With it, you can...

1. Track data using for individual app over mobile *and* wifi connections
2. Set a usage limit (unlimited, one time or monthly)
3. Restrict background data usage when near your data limit
4. Use the Data Sense service to reduce data usage when browsing (opt-in)

## Usage for a single day

The easiest way to monitor data usage for a single day is to...

1. Go into Data Sense app
2. Select **Settings** then **Set Limit**, select **Monthly**
3. Now set today as the 'Monthly reset date', then tap **Done**

When you view the Overview or Usage pivots, you should see the data usage for that day only.

**Note:** changing these settings *does not* delete previous data. You can try out the above, then undo the changes with out erasing the previous data usage.